# Extract certain pages from a pdf file based on a condition

Tags: pdf, conditional-statements, extract

I am trying to extract every page from a large pdf file whenever the sentence "quick analysis" is present on that page. I managed to load and read the file using PyPDF2 and even allocate all the pages where that sentence is present.

```
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(main_pdf)
String = "quick analysis"
for i in range(pdf.numPages):
    PageObj = pdf.getPage(i)
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
    if ResSearch != None:
       for n in range(i):
          pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter() 
           page = pdf.getPage(n)
           pdf_writer.addPage(page)
           with Path("Result.pdf").open(mode="wb") as output_file:
                pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

When I run the code, I get a pdf file named "Result" as an output which contains only the last page where the sentence "quick analysis" was allocated and not all of them. It means that the compiling process merges each page that has that sentence and then threw it out again. How can I make sure that every page counted is compiled and not skipped? Could you please help me out with this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't really get what the mistake is, I will try and save the found pages (hits) in an array before I run the loop. I am not sure if it is possible to store pdf pages that way though. When I moved the write after the looping I got the Result pdf file same as the base_pdf file.

Comment: I actually printed out "page_found" after the If statement, It printed out the right pages where the sentence was found, however, compiling the found_pages still yields only the last found page. :(